# Split on spaces which are not inside matching braces

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl (v5.30), I need to split strings on whitespace, which is not inside matching braces. For example:

```
"A {B C} D"   -> A|{B C}|D
"A{B C}D"     -> A{B C}D
"A{ B }C"     -> A{ B }C
"AB {C D} EF" -> AB|{C D}|EF
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can there be string like `AB {C { X Y } D} EF`  ?

Comment: Technically, yes, but I don't care about anything other than top-level braces.

Comment: **Helpful tips:** You can test your own regex on your own data via [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) or [Regexr](https://regexr.com/). If you make an account you can also save your test cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As long as `{` and `}` are balanced and there is no escaping you may use this regex for splitting on horizontal whitespaces that are not inside `{...}`:

```
/\h+(?![^{]*})/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1vREVU/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\h+`: Match 1 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(?![^{]*})`: Lookahead condition to assert a failure when we have 0 or more of non-`{` characters between current position and `}`

Comment: Excellent, that is very clever. I tried so many variations like this and this works.

Comment: This works as long as `{` and `}` are balanced *and unnested* and there is no escaping. This fails for `AB {C { X Y } D} EF` which the OP said  can happen.

Comment: You may be right but looking at question none of the shown examples have nested brackets. My answer would have been totally different if it was asked in question by giving clear examples.

Comment: Yes, the OP could have been clearer, but you didn't mention a major assumption you made. (Kudos for mentioning the other two, though.) And none of that changes the fact that this answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A regex-based solution will necessarily need to use recursion to handle nested braces.

```
my @a;
push @a, $1
   while
      $str =~ /
         \G
         \s*+
         (  (?: [^\s{}]++
            |   \{ (?&CURLY_BODY) \}
            )++
         )

         (?(DEFINE)
            (?<CURLY_BODY>
               (?: [^{}]++
               |   \{ (?&CURLY_BODY) \}
               )*+
            )
         )
      /xg;
```

Note that the above doesn't perform any validation, meaning it doesn't produces any errors on unmatched braces.

Comment: `Requires well-balanced braces` It shouldn't, it should match junk as well, -1. And you should be able to do it using  just 1 capture group,

Comment: @sln, Re "*it should match junk as well*", I don't know what you mean by that. I mean, the code I provided does accept junk. Of course, it returns junk when you do. Just like your solution.

Comment: `Just like your solution` Your's is nothing like my solution. Yours has standalone `\G` which gives up entirely when it doesn't match. Yours doesn't match unpaired braces (the junk)  Yours uses 2 capture groups. Ignoring the fact that whitespace is part of your match, and your regex uses 2 capture groups -  Your regex doesn't work for `AB {C { X Y } D} EF {as  {d}f` capture group 1 gives `AB|{C { X Y } D}|EF` instead of the desired `AB|{C { X Y } D}|EF|{as|{d}f`. You put emphasis on balanced  braces but don't handle them if not. You care not for defaults and all cases, your regex quits.

Comment: I never said it gives the same output as your solution.

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that maybe this expression,

```
my @arr = $str =~ /(?:\S+)?{[^}]*}(?:\S+)?|\S+/g;
```

might be just OK to look into.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ul6G6N/1/)

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
> explained on the top right panel of
> [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lEiC2w/1/). If you'd like, you
> can also watch in [this
> link](https://regex101.com/r/lEiC2w/1/debugger), how it would match
> against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thank you - I added two more examples as it's a bit more difficult than that I think - I suspect it might need some recursion somewhere.

Comment: Just updated again - with another test which causes trouble with that ...

Comment: Doesn't work on nested braces, which the OP said can occur.